# HighChart - Multiple Categories, Different Values, each value different column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was looking for a chart something like this.

[Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7yry.png)

In this chart the x-axis should have categories for the pair of stacked columns such as A,B,C,D where A is for the first two columns and B is for the second one respectively and in y-axis I just need count. I am sorry if this was asked before but I couldn't find it. Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic.

This can of course be customized to get it exactly how you want it.

More examples at https://www.highcharts.com/demo